# Getting Exception when using the Flink State Processor API to write a new SavePoint

Tags: java

I am getting an exception when using the Flink State Processor API to write a new SavePoint, which is

```
java.lang.Exception: Exception while creating StreamOperatorStateContext.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:204)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:247)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(OperatorChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$beforeInvoke$0(StreamTask.java:473)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:92)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.beforeInvoke(StreamTask.java:469)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:522)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:721)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:546)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not restore operator state backend for StreamSource_e8ea6e352a1a627513ffbd4573fa1628_(1/1) from any of the 1 provided restore options.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:135)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.operatorStateBackend(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:265)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:152)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.state.BackendBuildingException: Failed when trying to restore operator state backend
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackendBuilder.build(DefaultOperatorStateBackendBuilder.java:86)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateBackend.createOperatorStateBackend(RocksDBStateBackend.java:552)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.lambda$operatorStateBackend$0(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:256)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.attemptCreateAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:142)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:121)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing value for the key 'org.apache.flink.state.api.output.TaggedOperatorSubtaskState'
    at org.apache.flink.util.LinkedOptionalMap.unwrapOptionals(LinkedOptionalMap.java:190)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializerSnapshot.restoreSerializer(KryoSerializerSnapshot.java:86)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:545)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:438)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.NestedSerializersSnapshotDelegate.snapshotsToRestoreSerializers(NestedSerializersSnapshotDelegate.java:225)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.NestedSerializersSnapshotDelegate.getRestoredNestedSerializers(NestedSerializersSnapshotDelegate.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.CompositeTypeSerializerSnapshot.restoreSerializer(CompositeTypeSerializerSnapshot.java:204)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.StateSerializerProvider.previousSchemaSerializer(StateSerializerProvider.java:189)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.StateSerializerProvider.currentSchemaSerializer(StateSerializerProvider.java:164)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.RegisteredOperatorStateBackendMetaInfo.getPartitionStateSerializer(RegisteredOperatorStateBackendMetaInfo.java:113)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.OperatorStateRestoreOperation.restore(OperatorStateRestoreOperation.java:94)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackendBuilder.build(DefaultOperatorStateBackendBuilder.java:83)
    ... 15 more
```

My java code

```
public void createNewSavepoint(ExecutionEnvironment env, String savepointPath, StateBackend stateBackend,
                                   ParameterTool config) {
    String savepointOutputPath = config.get(EapSavepointConstants.EAP_SAVEPOINT_OUTPUT_PATH);
    try {
        ExistingSavepoint existingSavepoint = Savepoint.load(env, savepointPath, stateBackend);
        TypeSerializer<?>[] fieldSerializers = new TypeSerializer<?>[]{
                new KryoSerializer<>(KafkaTopicPartition.class, env.getConfig()),
                LongSerializer.INSTANCE
        };
        Class<Tuple2<KafkaTopicPartition, Long>> tuple2Class =
                (Class<Tuple2<KafkaTopicPartition, Long>>)(Class<?>) Tuple2.class;
        DataSet<Tuple2<KafkaTopicPartition, Long>> kafkaListState = existingSavepoint.readUnionState(
                "kafka_source_uid", "topic-partition-offset-states",
                TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Tuple2<KafkaTopicPartition, Long>>() {}),
                new TupleSerializer(tuple2Class, fieldSerializers));
        BootstrapTransformation kafkaTransformation = OperatorTransformation
                .bootstrapWith(kafkaListState)
                .transform(new KafkaSourceBootstrapFunction());
        Savepoint.create(stateBackend, 128)
                .withOperator("kafka_source_uid", kafkaTransformation)
                .write(savepointOutputPath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Savepoint load: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("print state: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to read the state about kafka in savepoint, and then generate a new savepoint to modify `max parallelism`, but when the new savepoint generated by this program is used to restart the flink task, the above mentitiond exception was thrown.

It spend long time for me, and I need some help, thanks.

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github ?

Comment: Just raised an issue in the flink community, the results will be updated here